# EF Core: Why are the foreign keys in my one-to-many association becoming outdated?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Scenario: I'm using EF Core 7 (code-first) to create a one-to-many association. The 'one' side is the class **VSDrawingWindowData**. The 'many' side is the class **LayoutElementData**. These classes describe a 2D window that owns/contains some icons.

My core issue is that **the one-to-many relationship is saved correctly the first time, but if I reload and save again, the relations are broken.**

I've made some edits to simplify my code, but this is basically what I have:

```
public class VSDrawingWindowData : INPC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LayoutElementData> Icons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LayoutElementData> { };
    private int translateX = 0;
     public int TranslateX
     {
         get { return translateX; }
         set
         {
             translateX = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }

 private int translateY = 0;
 public int TranslateY
 {
     get { return translateY; }
     set
     {
         translateY = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
     }
 }

 private double zoomFactor = 1.0;
 public double ZoomFactor
 {
     get { return zoomFactor; }
     set
     {
         zoomFactor = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
     }
 }
}

public abstract class LayoutElementData : INPC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public int? DrawingDataId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DrawingDataId")]
    public VSDrawingWindowData? DrawingData { get; set; }
   public int x;

   public int X
   {
       get
       {
           return x;
       }
       set
       {
           x = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   public int y;
   public int Y
   {
       get
       {
           return y;
       }
       set
       {
           y = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   private double baseWidth = 128.0;

   public double BaseWidth
   {
       get
       {
           return baseWidth;
       }
       set
       {
           baseWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   private double baseHeight = 128.0;

   public double BaseHeight
   {
       get
       {
           return baseHeight;
       }
       set
       {
           baseHeight = value; OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   new public double Width
   {
       get { return (int)(baseWidth * ScaleX); }
       set { ScaleX = value / baseWidth; OnPropertyChanged(); }
   }

   new public double Height
   {
       get { return (int)(baseHeight * ScaleY); }
       set { ScaleY = value / baseHeight; OnPropertyChanged(); }
   }

   private double scalex = 1.0;

   public double ScaleX
   {
       get
       {
           return scalex;
       }
       set
       {
           scalex = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   private double scaley = 1.0;
   public double ScaleY
   {
       get
       {
           return scaley;
       }
       set
       {
           scaley = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the Snapshot created after my first initial-create migration:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity("VitalSimCore.VSDrawingWindowData", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<int>("TranslateX")
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<int>("TranslateY")
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<double>("ZoomFactor")
                    .HasColumnType("REAL");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.ToTable("Drawings");
            });


        modelBuilder.Entity("VitalSimCore.LayoutElementData", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<double>("BaseHeight")
                    .HasColumnType("REAL");

                b.Property<double>("BaseWidth")
                    .HasColumnType("REAL");

                b.Property<string>("Discriminator")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                b.Property<int?>("DrawingDataId")
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<int>("ElementType")
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<double>("Height")
                    .HasColumnType("REAL");

                b.Property<double>("ScaleX")
                    .HasColumnType("REAL");

                b.Property<double>("ScaleY")
                    .HasColumnType("REAL");

                b.Property<double>("Width")
                    .HasColumnType("REAL");

                b.Property<int>("X")
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<int>("Y")
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("DrawingDataId");

                b.ToTable("LayoutElements");

                b.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator").HasValue("LayoutElementData");

                b.UseTphMappingStrategy();
            });
```

My direct observations are:

1. Create a new `VSDrawingWindowData` object in code. Add some instances of `LayoutElementData` to the Icons collection. Save to database. The initially-created `VSDrawingWindowData` has ID=1, and all of the `LayoutElementData` instances in the database have `DrawingDataId=1`.
2. I close my application, then re-launch a new instance. I load database contents. Everything loads correctly (all `LayoutElementData` still have `DrawingDataId=1`). The loaded `VSDrawingWindowData` object has `ID=1`. Everything is as expected. The `dbContext` is now discarded.
3. As part of my code's 'pre-save' operation, all rows in the database are deleted using a dedicated `dbContext` for the database-clearing step. I've confirmed that the results are as-expecting using SQLite DB Browser after this step. All tables exist, no rows exist.
4. My code creates a new dbContext, and adds the parent `VSDrawingWindowData` to the `dbContext`. Using the debugger, I have confirmed at this point that the parent `VSDrawingWindowData` still has `ID=1`, although I understand this may not be relevant since EF Core increments the ID on save.
5. The parent `VSDrawingWindowData` object still contains all the expected `LayoutElementData` instances in its Icons collection.
6. In the debugger, I've confirmed that all of the `LayoutElementData` instances have been 'added' to the `dbContext`. At this point, they have the `DrawingDataId=1` value they loaded from the database, but I've also tried setting the ID to null, and got the same results. They also have the navigation property DrawingData set to the intended parent `VSDrawingWindowData` object.
7. Call `dbContext.BulkSaveChanges()` after adding everything to the database.
8. Manually inspect the database. The `LayoutElementData` objects retain the original `DrawingDataId` they originally had (1), but the `VSDrawingWindowData` is now stored in the database with `ID=2`. This causes errors in my project-load function because the 'many' side points at an element that doesn't exist.

Probably unrelated: in my database-load function, I set NoTracking:

```
db.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

This is because my intention is to delete everything from the database and re-save everything. I wanted to rely on a complete re-write for initial simplicity, and possibly take advantage of change-tracking later on. However, I've just tested disabling the no-tracking (leaving the `dbContext` in the default mode) with no change in result. This is what I expect, because I discard the database context after the loading operation, so whether it's in tracking-mode should have no effect. A separate context is used for saving, and this mode also leaves the `dbContext` in the default mode.

I think I'm probably making a simple error in my code-first or usage of EF Core, but I can't see the issue after watching several EF Core tutorials. How does EF Core correctly assign `DrawingDataId` the first time, and then keep it as `ID=1` in the future even after the ID of the parent object has changed?

Note: I've read a lot of StackOverflow posts on EF Core one-to-many issues. Some are tangentially related but they are not exactly the same as this issue. Happy to take a look if you believe this really is a duplicate of another post.

--- More Info ---

Here is the (slightly redacted) contents of my 'clear database' function, which is called before saving:

```
public static void ClearDb(string path)
{
    using (var manager = new VSDatabaseManager(path))
    {
        manager.Database.Migrate();
        manager.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE");
        manager.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        manager.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DELETE FROM Drawings");
        manager.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DELETE FROM LayoutElements");
        manager.BulkSaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And here is the (slightly redacted) insertion function:

```
public static void SaveProjectToDb(Project Proj, string path)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    using (var manager = new VSDatabaseManager(path))
    {
        manager.Database.Migrate();
        manager.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE");
        foreach (var d in Proj.Drawings)
        {
            manager.Drawings.Add(d.Data);
        }
        manager.BulkSaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In answer to the question of why I would bother with a database if I'm deleting and re-saving every time: in my case, I'm using the database as the file storage format for a relatively complex data-type for a desktop application. It doesn't necessarily have to be a database, but I found that expressing my data-types as JSON turned out the be quite inefficient. There is self-referential data in other tables (which I'm not having trouble with here, so we can ignore it), and it's tricky to express self-referential data in JSON without using something equivalent to an index field. Feel free to propose an alternative, but for now, I'm sure this is possible to express in EF Core even if the usage appears to be somewhat non-standard. I would prefer to debug this issue as a question on its own, rather than thinking about whether to use entirely different data-storage systems right now.

**"Deleting rows from a table using an identity column will not reset the identity sequence"**: I understand this. I'm not so much confused by the fact that the parent object is getting a new ID. I'm confused why the child objects aren't being 'relationship-fixed' by EF Core on save.

**trying to reinsert untracked related entities won't work as identity columns will be regenerated but FKs won't. You need to re-associate the newly created entities.** I suppose this is where my understanding is unclear. When I initially add the parent object to the dbContext, somehow EF Core is able to correctly assign the corresponding foreign-key to the children the first time the structure is saved. Why isn't deleting everything from the database, and re-adding, equivalent to the first add-to-context operation?

Comment: Not sure I understand why you would bother with a database if you want to delete everything every run, or do you mean by "delete everything" just deleting the aggregate root (parent and all related children) then re-inserting. The issue in that case is likely going to be identity columns. Deleting rows from a table using an identity column will not reset the identity sequence, and trying to reinsert untracked related entities won't work as identity columns will be regenerated but FKs won't. You need to re-associate the newly created entities. Add code for how you delete+insert in this case.

Comment: @StevePy added details in the question text

Comment: So is the call to SaveProjectToDb given a brand new Project in both cases? For instance for the initial insert you need to obviously create the new parent and associate the new children instances. Is that happening the exact same way the second time you save, or is it being called with a previously loaded (and untracked) entity structure the second time?

Comment: @StevePy The second time, it's called with a previously-loaded and untracked entity. The Project object itself is not stored in the database, but the VSDrawingWindowData object and LayoutElementData objects are previously-loaded and explicity untracked, obtained from a discarded dbContext.

Comment: In that case as a work-around you can try setting each of the layout elements DrawingDataId and DrawingData references to #null prior to adding the DrawingData to the new DbContext instance.  After inserting, all records should have new PKs and the FKs should be re-populated.

Comment: @StevePy That seems to have done the trick. I didn't realize a populated navigation property would 'block' foreign-key assignment. I'll accept this as an answer if you want to submit it. Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: All good, I don't know of any explicit documentation around this but it likely falls under situations where you have both navigation properties, FK properties and bi-directional references that the change tracker can get "mixed up" over, where the general advice is update via one or the other and avoid updating both. ("Changing relationships using foreign key values" under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided in the comments, I'm just documenting it here for clarity.

Setting both the FK and the navigation property to null from the 'many' side fixed/worked around this issue.

There's some Microsoft documentation on foreign keys and 'relationship fixup' here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes

However, I don't see any specific sentence in this documentation covering this scenario. The suggestion is to 'only update one side of the relationship' in order to prevent 'doing too much work' but it seems that in my scenario, EF Core has the necessary information to make the right choice, but does something else.

I will post back here if I have more clarification about why this happens.

---- Edit ----
It now appears that my issue was caused by a bug in the Entity Framework Extensions library.

Based on my testing, this issue only occurs when I call the extension method .BulkSaveChanges on my database. Using the default .SaveChanges() function results in no foreign-key constraint violations.

I've reported the issue here:
https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/issues/569

It seems that it's not necessary for me to explicitly set the parent-references to null or anything like that, .SaveChanges() seems to be updating everything to use the correct foreign-keys based on the objects graph when it's saved.